# ansible: AnsibleModule.log() method does not print anything to stdout/stderr

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write a custom `ansible` module.

I need to have some debug info during module execution.

However the following lines fo not print anything even with the highest verbosity level enabled (`-vvvv`) and with `export ANSIBLE_DEBUG=true`

```
from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule

module.log(msg="some_message"))
```

The only time I am ever able to see some `msg` printed is via the following method:

```
module.exit_json(changed=True, msg=_msg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be emphasized that `AnsibleModule.log()` will **not** send the output to neither `stout` or `stderr`. It will send it to the default system logging facility.

In my case this was `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: on target host or on deployer host?

Comment: How do I know my  default system logging facility , using WSL2